# Fast splitting of pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
      0   1
 0   john 14 
 1   jack 2  
 2   emma 6
 3   john 23    
 4   john 53
 5   jack 43
```

that is really large(1+GB). I want to split the dataframe by name and to execute code on each of the resulting dataframes. This is my code, that works:

```
df.sort(columns=[0], inplace=True)
df.set_index(keys=[0], drop=False, inplace=True)
names = df[0].unique().tolist()
for name in names:
    name_df = df.loc[df[0] == name]
    do_stuff(name_df)
```

However it runs **really slow**. Is there a faster way to accomplish this task?

Comment: won't `df.groupby(0).apply(do_stuff)` work? or `df.groupby('0').apply(do_stuff)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an dictionary comprehension example that simply adds together each sub dataframe grouped on name:

```
>>> {k: gb['1'].sum() for k, gb in df.groupby('0')}
{'emma': 6, 'jack': 45, 'john': 90}
```

For something more complicated, you can create a function and then apply it to the group.

```
def foo(df):
    df += 1
    df *= 2
    df = df.sum()
    return df

{k: g['1'].apply(foo) for k, g in df.groupby('0')}
```